# Xcode 9.2 Archive Succeed but unable to Export IPA

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I am trying to continuous integrate for an Enterprise IOS Build for AdhocProd. Using below command for Build and Archive .

Build Command:

```
    /usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace "Project.xcworkspace" -scheme 
    "ProjectiOSPROD" -archivePath build/ProjectiOS -configuration Release 
    archive CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual 
   PROVISIONING_PROFILE=”CompanyNameProdAdhocDistribution” 
   CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: Build Machine(XXXXXX)" 
    PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER="com.Companyname.prod.ProjectiOS"
```

OUTPUT:
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

Export Command:

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "build/ProjectiOS.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/ProjectiOS.ipa" -exportOptionsPlist"../../ExportOptions.plist"
```

This Plist is ExportOptions.Plist taken from the xcode IDE. and using  it for jenkins work space

Output:

```
error: exportArchive: SDWebImage.framework does not support provisioning profiles.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=10 "SDWebImage.framework does not support provisioning profiles." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=SDWebImage.framework does not support provisioning profiles., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=SDWebImage.framework does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile CompanyNameProdAdhocDistribution has been manually specified. Remove this item from the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}

error: exportArchive: Stripe.framework does not support provisioning profiles.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=10 "Stripe.framework does not support provisioning profiles." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Stripe.framework does not support provisioning profiles., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stripe.framework does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile CompanyNameProdAdhocDistribution has been manually specified. Remove this item from the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
```

provisioningProfiles  dictionary is already present in Property list. If i removed this it says add this to Property list.

Any Suggestions would be greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have to generate and export the IPA manually with Xcode9.2. This will create a file name ExportOptions.plist in the exported folder.
- Copy that file to workspace root folder.
- Write below command in Execute shell.

  ```
  xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ${WORKSPACE}/build/YourProject.xcarchive -exportPath ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/archive -exportOptionsPlist ${WORKSPACE}/ExportOptions.plist
  ```